# Change Google+ URL to a custom one

Tags: google-plus

Google+ is offering me a custom URL for the page of my company. It says that I'm pre-approved for that particularly URL but I'd like to try to get a different one (based on the name of our company instead of just the URL).

Is it possible to request a custom URL from Google+? How?

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible at the moment, 30th of October 2013. The URL you are offered is the only one you can use.

It was previously possible but the option has been removed during this roll-out.

There is no comment on if this option will be provided in the future.

Currently:

[image: Current Custom URL option]

Previous:

[image: Previous Custom URL option]

For those no good at spotting the difference, look at the bottom, next to the “Not now” button—`Don't like this URL? Request a different one`.

Comment: Unfortunately, the images were resized to the point they are illegible.

Comment: Yes, sorry, updated with new images.

Answer (score 2):

As of 12th November 2013 further options have been provided, albeit limited ones.

You are offered a custom URL for your page and given the option to add a suffix to it.
[image: Google Plus URL Options]

If you click through you are given the option to add your suffix.
[image: Google Plus URL Options]

There are no options provided apart from adding a suffix to the URL offered to you by Google.

Answer (score 1):

> **Expanding the availability of custom URLs**
>   …
>   Meanwhile, any brand or business that has a linked website or is a verified local business can claim a custom URL for their Google+ page. Link and verification info is available in the Google+ Help Center: http://goo.gl/RMpxP.

From [Vic Gundotra’s Google+ page](https://plus.google.com/+VicGundotra/posts/AUKxL1Sj1WG).